# Некорректное отображение стиля шрифта Open Sans "Sofia Sans"

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, шрифты

Пытался добавить на сайт шрифт SofiaSans regular, но заметил что некорректно отображаются некоторые символы, если в теге html установлено **lang="ru"**, но при **lang="en"** все работает корректно.
Пытался исправить ситуацию с помощью ***font-feature-settings: "ss02" 1;***, но ничего не меняется.

Проблема именно в выборе языка. Как-то можно исправить ситуацию? Просто писать lang="en", когда у тебя сайт на русском, только чтобы шрифт работал как надо, как-то неправильно.

На скриншотах показал как это работает

[image: Правильное отображение шрифта при Lang="en"]
[image: Некорректное отображение шрифта при Lang="ru"]

Comment: А в чём собственно некорректность-то? В русском и болгарском традиционно разное начертание некоторых букв.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте отключить [локализованные формы](https://helpx.adobe.com/ru/fonts/using/open-type-syntax.html#locl):

```html
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sofia+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .Sofia-Sans {
      font-family: 'Sofia Sans', sans-serif;
      font-feature-settings: 'locl' 0;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="Sofia-Sans">12133 Лл А ываыа ывВ</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Можете использовать [`font-feature-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override). Нужно корневому элементу (то-есть `<html>`) установить CSS свойство `font-feature-settings`, со значением `'ENG'`, вот так:

```css
html {
    font-language-override: 'ENG';
}
```

Тогда иероглифы будут отображаться в соответствии с указанным языком, то-есть в данном случае, английским. Сам `font-language-override` переопределяет поведение отображения шрифта и работает независимо от атрибута `lang` в корневом элементе.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia+Sans);

html {
  font-language-override: 'ENG';
}

.sofiasans-regular {
  font-family: 'Sofia Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">

<body>
  <div class="sofiasans-regular">12133 Лл А ываыа ывВ</div>
</body>

</html>
```